# bookshelf and knex initialization error

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am trying to setup a mysql connection in node js using bookshelf and knex. This is my setup:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'my_user',
    password : 'my_password',
    database : 'my_db',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  }
});
var DB = require('bookshelf')(knex);
module.exports.DB = DB;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: [object KnexClient] is not a valid Knex client, did you misspell it?
    at new Knex (/Users/arenduchintala/Projects/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/knex/knex.js:48:17)
    at new Bookshelf (/Users/arenduchintala/Projects/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/bookshelf/bookshelf.js:43:14)
    at Bookshelf (/Users/arenduchintala/Projects/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/bookshelf/bookshelf.js:37:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arenduchintala/Projects/MacaronicWebApp/db.js:11:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arenduchintala/Projects/MacaronicWebApp/model.js:1:72)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Looks like the line : `require('bookshelf')(knex)` throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an old version of bookshelf, I changed it in `package.json` from:
`"bookshelf" : "0.5"` to `"bookshelf" : "*"` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

run
`npm i --s mysql`
it requires this package